# How to recover files and folders from /tmp?

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I mistakenly placed my backup into the `/tmp` folder and now when I try to move those files to `/home` using `cp -r`, I lost everything in my `/tmp`.

The command I used was:

```bsh
cp -r /tmp /home
```

Please help me recover my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use some recover tools like **Testdisk** or **PhotoRec** .

TestDisk can recover lost partitions of virtually any filesystem. PhotoRec can recover files of most types, including most picture and video formats. PhotoRec can be used on existing partitions, or can be used to recover files on deleted partitions without having to recover the underlying partitions.

Possible setups for recovery include:

```
Recover the files to a separate hard drive.
Recover the files to a networked storage drive.
Recover the files to a separate partition on the same hard drive.
Image the hard drive using a tool like ddrescue and recover files using only one partition.
```

Download them [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download), both tools are in the same package.

Install the package and try your luck, I hope you can recover your lost files.

[Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304050556/https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/storage/8257-how-to-recover-lost-files-after-you-accidentally-wipe-your-hard-drive)

Answer (score -1):

If you run `cp -r /tmp /home` command with superuser privileges(sudo), your `/tmp` directory must be inside `/home` directory (`/home/tmp`). You can access the files by cding into `/home/tmp` directory  or you can move to that directory through nautilus.

Once you find the files, copy those to any other location and then restart your PC.

Comment: ok .. But i /tmp has mounted with separate partion with  /dev/sda5       138G   78M  131G   1% /tmp

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /home`

Comment: dr-x------  2 administrator administrator  4096 May 10 11:32 administrator
drwx------  2 root          root          16384 May 10 11:22 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 22 siva          siva           4096 May 20 11:50 siva

Comment: What's the exact command you tried?

Comment: post the output of `tail -10 ~/.bash_history` in your question.

Comment: cp -r siva/ /home/siva/
 exit
 ls
 cd /home/siva/
 ls
 cd siva/
 ls
 cd siva/