# How to recover deleted files in specific partitions?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I had windows 8 installed on my computer and had four partitions. I installed Ubuntu. And checked the option instead of windows 8. 
Instead of installing Ubuntu in the partition it just formatted the while hard drive and made just one drive and all of the other data is gone. I want to recover those files how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some recover tools like `Testdisk` or `PhotoRec` .

`TestDisk` can recover lost partitions of virtually any filesystem. `PhotoRec` can recover files of most types, including most picture and video formats. PhotoRec can be used on existing partitions, or can be used to recover files on deleted partitions without having to recover the underlying partitions.

Refer to this Question [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469477/how-to-recover-a-files-and-folders-from-tmp-location/469481#469481)